# Como aumentar marcas de escala do eixo Y em gráficos no ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2, r, tidyverse

Tenho um gráfico com marcas de escala muito longas entre si, gostaria de aumentar a quantidade, mas não sei como é possível.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de aumentar a quantidade de valores no eixo Y, por exemplo, entre 32 e 256 e entre 2048 e 16384.

Código que estou utilizando:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gghighlight)

url <- httr::GET("https://xx9p7hp1p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/PortalGeral",
                 httr::add_headers("X-Parse-Application-Id" =
                                     "unAFkcaNDeXajurGB7LChj8SgQYS2ptm")) %>%
  httr::content() %>%
  '[['("results") %>%
  '[['(1) %>%
  '[['("arquivo") %>%
  '[['("url")

dados <- utils::read.csv2(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fileEncoding = "latin1")
dados$data <- lubridate::as_date(dados$data)

dados <- dados %>%
  filter(data > as.Date("2020-02-29"))

rm(url)

dados %>%
  filter(casosAcumulados > 9) %>%
  group_by(estado) %>%
  mutate(diasposdez = 1:n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(diasposdez, casosAcumulados)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = estado)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log2') +
  labs(x = "Dias depois do 10º caso confirmado", y = "Casos acumulados") +
  gghighlight(estado == c("DF", "SP", "RJ", "AM", "CE")) +
  ggthemes::scale_colour_economist() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey10")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "dashed"), plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 11))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use o argumento `breaks` da função `scale_y_continous`:

```
dados %>%
    filter(casosAcumulados > 9) %>%
    group_by(estado) %>%
    mutate(diasposdez = 1:n()) %>%
    ggplot(aes(diasposdez, casosAcumulados)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = estado)) +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log2', breaks = 2^(3:15)) +
    labs(x = "Dias depois do 10º caso confirmado", y = "Casos acumulados") +
    gghighlight(estado == c("DF", "SP", "RJ", "AM", "CE")) +
    ggthemes::scale_colour_economist() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey10")) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "dashed"), plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 11))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qualquer vetor numérico pode ser utilizado para personalizar os breaks do eixo y (e, consequentemente, do eixo x utilizando a função `scale_x_continuous`).

```
dados %>%
    filter(casosAcumulados > 9) %>%
    group_by(estado) %>%
    mutate(diasposdez = 1:n()) %>%
    ggplot(aes(diasposdez, casosAcumulados)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = estado)) +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log2', breaks = c(2^(3:8), 2^(11:15))) +
    labs(x = "Dias depois do 10º caso confirmado", y = "Casos acumulados") +
    gghighlight(estado == c("DF", "SP", "RJ", "AM", "CE")) +
    ggthemes::scale_colour_economist() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey10")) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "dashed"), plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 11))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque não `labels = trans_format("log2", scales::math_format(2^.x))` a seguir ao argumento `breaks` apesar de não ser perguntado? (+1, já agora).

Comment: Boa sugestão. Como o AP tinha colocado a escala com seus valores numéricos calculados, não pensei que fosse necessário colocá-los em forma de potência de 2. No fim, acho que depende do fim ao qual o gráfico se propõe. Se for algo voltado ao público leigo, particularmente me agrada mais ver os números assim calculados do que em forma de potência.